# SQL query that is able to count days based on event queries

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, count, date

I have a table with the following data:

```
id    date_changed                  color_start         color_end
-------------------------------------------------------------------

1     2020-05-27 16:33:52.000       green                yellow
1     2020-06-11 20:12:18.000       yellow               red
1     2020-06-11 20:20:58.000       red                  green
2     2021-03-03 14:31:44.000       yellow               red
2     2020-08-06 14:59:21.000       green                yellow              
3     2021-04-28 12:36:45.000       green                red
...
```

Fore example, item with id #2 went from green to yellow on 2020-08-06 14:59:21 and then on 2021-03-03 14:31:44 it went from yellow to read. I need to count how many items were in green, yellow, red state between two time ranges.

I tried the following query by doing some research to basically list events or everyday for the past year, but it is not really what I want.

```
SELECT d.date, items.id,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as yellow_count,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as green_count,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as red_count,
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE null end) + 
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE null END) + 
count(CASE WHEN items.color_end = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as total_count
FROM (SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
      FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS offs
     ) d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     events items
     ON d.date = to_char(date_trunc('day', item.date_changed), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY d.date, items.id;
```

Comment: can you paste what you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that your data model is flawed.

You have 6 records:

```
id    date_changed                  color_start         color_end
-------------------------------------------------------------------

1     2020-05-27 16:33:52.000       green                yellow
1     2020-06-11 20:12:18.000       yellow               red
1     2020-06-11 20:20:58.000       red                  green
2     2021-03-03 14:31:44.000       yellow               red
2     2020-08-06 14:59:21.000       green                yellow              
3     2021-04-28 12:36:45.000       green                red
```

You **should** have 9 records. So, your record structure **should be** this (example for `id` = 1 only):

```
id    date_from               date_to                        status

1   -infinity,                2020-05-27 16:33:52+01         green
1   2020-05-27 16:33:52+01,   2020-06-11 20:12:18+01        yellow
1   2020-06-11 20:12:18+01,   2020-06-11 20:20:58+01           red
1   2020-06-11 20:20:58+01    +infinity                      green
```

You are trying to record two states in one record in two different fields. So, there are two possible refactoring solutions:

- revise your schema (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fcf5064d9d839dae6b502fbf0a8a78bb)). Even if you don't (or can't) change your underlying tables, you can use a Common Table Expression ([`CTE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/)) to refactor your current data and then query off that. A permanent refactoring would be **vastly** preferable!
- revised schema using the `TSTZRANGE` [data type](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=23e7ac021c37404a0373e1b044f094e4) (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8442a6115bce114db9a43182f2e6f83b)).

You might also like to consider what I term "auxiliary" solutions - i.e. roll-your-own triggers or possibly  [`Temporal Tables`](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables) - currently only available as a (non-contrib) PostgreSQL extension. If I had any criticisms of PostgreSQL, one of them would be that they haven't implemented this natively (yet)!

We start with the tables/data as is:

```
--
--  Original table design from the OP
--

CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  dc TIMESTAMPTZ(0) NOT NULL,  -- all times are xx:yy:zz.000, so use a precision of 0
  cs TEXT NOT NULL,
  ce TEXT NOT NULL,
  
  UNIQUE (id, dc),
  CHECK (cs != ce)
);
```

the records:

```
--
--  OP's data
--

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, '2020-05-27 16:33:52', 'green',  'yellow'),
(1, '2020-06-11 20:12:18', 'yellow', 'red'),
(1, '2020-06-11 20:20:58', 'red',    'green'),

(2, '2020-08-06 14:59:21', 'green',  'yellow'),              
(2, '2021-03-03 14:31:44', 'yellow', 'red'),

(3, '2021-04-28 12:36:45', 'green',  'red');
```

### 1st solution - two [`TIMESTAMPTZ`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/) fields per record (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fcf5064d9d839dae6b502fbf0a8a78bb)):

We start by using the [`LAG()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/) and [`LEAD()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lead-function/) PostgreSQL [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html). Window functions are incredibly powerful and well worth learning. They will repay any effort spent studying them many times over.

```
--
--  "Foundation" query - using this as a Common Table Expression, we can refactor our
--  data - or better yet, refactor our base tables in our system.
--

SELECT
  id,
  COALESCE(LAG(dc)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc), '-INFINITY') AS lag_dc,
  cs,
  dc,
  COALESCE(LEAD(dc) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc),  'INFINITY') AS lead_dc,
  ce
FROM
  test;
```

Result (better viewed on the fiddle):

```
id        lag_dc           cs            dc               lead_dc             ce
1   -infinity              green    2020-05-27 16:33:52+01  2020-06-11 20:12:18+01  yellow
1   2020-05-27 16:33:52+01 yellow   2020-06-11 20:12:18+01  2020-06-11 20:20:58+01             red
1   2020-06-11 20:12:18+01 red      2020-06-11 20:20:58+01  infinity    green
2   -infinity              green    2020-08-06 14:59:21+01  2021-03-03 14:31:44+00  yellow
2   2020-08-06 14:59:21+01 yellow   2021-03-03 14:31:44+00  infinity    red
3   -infinity              green    2021-04-28 12:36:45+01  infinity    red
```

I won't reproduce every query on the fiddle - here is the first:

```
--
-- We get the first record of each set (by id) - from '-INFINITY' to the first 
-- date_changed (dc)
--

WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    COALESCE(LAG(dc)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc), '-INFINITY') AS lag_dc,
    cs,
    dc,
    COALESCE(LEAD(dc) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc),  'INFINITY') AS lead_dc,
    ce
  FROM
    test
)
SELECT
  c1.id, c1.lag_dc AS df, c1.dc AS dt, c1.cs
FROM cte1 c1 WHERE lag_dc = '-INFINITY';
```

Result:

```
id      df              dt               cs
1   -infinity   2020-05-27 16:33:52+01  green
2   -infinity   2020-08-06 14:59:21+01  green
3   -infinity   2021-04-28 12:36:45+01  green
```

Then we `UNION` three of these queries:

- the first record in each `id` set,
- the middle records of each group,
- last record per `id`.

as follows:

```
--
-- We now obtain the union of all 3 sets and we have our result!
--

WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    COALESCE(LAG(dc)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc), '-INFINITY') AS lag_dc,
    cs,
    dc,
    COALESCE(LEAD(dc) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc),  'INFINITY') AS lead_dc,
    ce
  FROM
    test
)
SELECT 
  c1.id, 
  c1.lag_dc AS "Date from:", 
  c1.dc     AS "Date to:", 
  c1.cs     AS "Colour"  
FROM cte c1 
WHERE lag_dc = '-INFINITY'  -- first records
UNION ALL
SELECT  
  c2.id, c2.dc, c2.lead_dc, c2.ce FROM cte c2 WHERE lead_dc = 'INFINITY'  -- last records
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  c3.id, c3.dc, c3.lead_dc, c3.ce FROM cte c3  WHERE c3.lead_dc != 'INFINITY'  -- middle records
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Result:

```
id  Date from:               Date to:               Colour
 1  -infinity                2020-05-27 16:33:52+01 green
 1  2020-05-27 16:33:52+01   2020-06-11 20:12:18+01 yellow
 1  2020-06-11 20:12:18+01   2020-06-11 20:20:58+01 red
 1  2020-06-11 20:20:58+01  infinity                green
 2  -infinity                2020-08-06 14:59:21+01 green
 2  2020-08-06 14:59:21+01   2021-03-03 14:31:44+00 yellow
 2  2021-03-03 14:31:44+00   infinity               red
 3  -infinity                2021-04-28 12:36:45+01 green
 3  2021-04-28 12:36:45+01   infinity               red
```

This makes querying the data relatively simple - two sample queries.

### 1st Sample Query: Changes of status (`colour`) in 2021:

```
--
-- Records where the beginning and the end of the range falls 
-- anywhere >= 2021:01:01 00:00:00
--
-- It's bascially a record of any changes in status in 2021!
--

SELECT
  *
FROM
  test_rs
WHERE ts_from >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00' ANd ts_to >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY id, ts_from;
```

Result:

```
id  ts_from                 ts_to       colour
2   2021-03-03 14:31:44+00  infinity       red
3   2021-04-28 12:36:45+01  infinity       red
```

### 2nd Sample Query: Count of status at a point in time (New Year's Day 2021):

```
--
--  Status counts at exactly New Year, 2021 - we know that at the point, we had two
--  entities with status green and 1 with status yellow
--

SELECT 
  colour, COUNT(colour)
FROM
  test_rs
WHERE ts_from <= '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND ts_to >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY colour
ORDER BY colour;
```

Result:

```
colour    count
green         2
yellow        1
```

### 2nd solution - a single [`TSTZRANGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) field per record (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8442a6115bce114db9a43182f2e6f83b)):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html), we have inclusive and exclusive bounds and infinite (or unbounded - perhaps a better term) bounds - i.e. `[` or `]` are inclusive bounds and `(` and `)` are exclusive bounds. Also, `[,` or `(,` is unbounded upper and unbounded for the closing brackets (`,]` or `,)`) .

### Refactoring query for Time Stamp ranges:

I won't go through all of the queries to obtain the end result - it's a similar process to the one used above. Only the final query is displayed:

```
WITH cte AS
(

--
--  We don't need COALESCE in this case, since the range treats 'NULL' as -INFINITY
--  or +INFIITY depending on whether it's at the beginning or end of the range.
--

  SELECT
    id,
    LAG(dc)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc) AS lag_dc,
    cs,
    dc,
    LEAD(dc) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dc) AS lead_dc,
    ce
  FROM
    test
)
SELECT
  c.id, 
  TSTZRANGE(c.lag_dc, c.dc, '[)') AS "Date from:/Date to:", 
  c.cs AS "Colour"
FROM cte c WHERE c.lag_dc IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.id, TSTZRANGE(c.dc, c.lead_dc, '[)'), c.ce 
FROM cte c WHERE lead_dc IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT c.id, TSTZRANGE(c.dc, c.lead_dc, '[)'), c.ce 
FROM cte c 
WHERE c.lead_dc != 'INFINITY'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Result:

```
id     Date from:/Date to:                                Colour
1   (,"2020-05-27 16:33:52+01")                            green
1   ["2020-05-27 16:33:52+01","2020-06-11 20:12:18+01")   yellow
1   ["2020-06-11 20:12:18+01","2020-06-11 20:20:58+01")      red
1   ["2020-06-11 20:20:58+01",)                            green
2   (,"2020-08-06 14:59:21+01")                            green
2   ["2020-08-06 14:59:21+01","2021-03-03 14:31:44+00")   yellow
2   ["2021-03-03 14:31:44+00",)                              red
3   (,"2021-04-28 12:36:45+01")                            green
3   ["2021-04-28 12:36:45+01",)                              red
```

### 1st sample query: Change of status any time **after** the beginning of 2021.

```
--
-- Records where the beginning and the end of the range falls 
-- anywhere >= 2021:01:01 00:00:00
--
-- It's bascially a record of any changes in status in 2021!
--

SELECT * FROM test_rs
WHERE 
LOWER(df_dt) > '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND
df_dt && TSTZRANGE('2021-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, NULL, '[)');
```

Result:

```
id        df_dt                   colour
2   ["2021-03-03 14:31:44+00",)      red
3   ["2021-04-28 12:36:45+01",)      red
```

We can see that this is equivalent to the first sample query with the range field in place of the two timestamps.

The `WHERE` clause is worth looking at: `LOWER(df_dt)` and `WHERE trb && TSTZRANGE('2021-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, NULL, '[)');` - it makes use of the `&&` (overlaps) operator (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html) - I also found [this post](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/04/postgresql-data-types-ranges/) helpful).

So, we can see that any time range that overlaps with anytime from `2021-01-01 00:00:00` onwards (`...MPTZ, NULL, '[)');` is picked up - note the `NULL` in constructing the `TSTZRANGE` value(s).

### 2nd query: colour count at **exactly** the beginning of 2021.

```
--
--  Status counts at exactly New Year, 2021 - we know that at the point, we had two
--  entities with status green and 1 with status yellow
--

SELECT colour, COUNT(colour) FROM test_rs
WHERE df_dt && TSTZRANGE('2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 00:00:00', '[]')
GROUP BY colour;
```

Result (same as for 2nd sample query with two timestamps):

```
colour    count
 green        2
yellow        1
```

### Auxiliary solutions:

There are other ways of refactoring your schema (and or app code) to track changes in the database, in particular for tables referencing timestamp fields - a complete discussion of these is beyond the scope of this answer, but you might like to consider the following:

- roll your own using triggers or
- install Vlad Arkhipov's [`Temporal Table`](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables) solution. I have used this in a POC and it appears to work quite well, but has nothing like the functionality of, say, [MariaDB's solution](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-tables/). This involves compiling and installing a `C` based extension.
- install Vik Fearing's (a PostgreSQL Major Contributor) [temporal table extension](https://github.com/xocolatl/periods) (also in `C`). I haven't used it, but the fact that the guy is a major contributor speaks for itself. As of the time of writing, appears to be the most up to date!
- Near Form's [`temporal_tables`](https://github.com/nearform/temporal_tables) functionality, which according to the github link is: `a temporal_tables extension in PL/pgSQL, without the need for external c extension. The goal is to be able to use it on AWS RDS and other hosted solutions, where using custom extensions or c functions is not an option`. Sounds interesting, but I haven't tried it so can't comment.